# ExtJS 4.2 ComboBox not showing model field that is a combination of fields

Tags: extjs, combobox

I've come across a rather interesting problem. I have a store, which uses a model. My model looks like this:

```
Ext.define('HealOmni.model.device_model', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

requires: [
    'Ext.data.Field'
],

fields: [
    {
        name: 'device_id'
    },
    {
        name: 'device_name'
    },
    {
        name: 'device_id_real'
    },
    {
        name: 'sim_number'
    },
    {
        name: 'other_device_details'
    },
    {
        convert: function(v, rec) {
            return rec.get('device_name') + " " + rec.get('device_id_real');
        },
        name: 'device_name_and_id'
    }
]
});
```

and then this store is used by a ComboBox, the combo box looks like this:

```
xtype: 'combobox',
height: 30,
itemId: 'deviceID',
fieldLabel: 'Device ID',
labelClsExtra: 'screenSharingFontLowerHalf',
labelSeparator: ' ',
displayField: 'device_name_and_id',
queryMode: 'local',
store: 'userDeviceManagementLoggedInDisplay',
valueField: 'device_id_real'
```

I use the combination field `device_name_and_id` as the display field of the combobox. However, when I reloaded my site, it seemed that the ComboBox could not display the field properly. When I use the other fields, let's say `device_id`, it displays just fine. It's only the combination field that does not display and I don't know why.

I log the values to console after I load the store and all fields are displayed, even the combination ones -- so I'm really rather confused as to why the ComboBox won't display properly.

Does anyone know how to show a "convert" field in a combobox?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below fiddle
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1m9t

```
    Ext.define('HealOmni.model.device_model', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'device_name_and_id',
        convert: function (v, rec) {
            return rec.get('device_name') + " " + rec.get('device_id');
        }
    }]
});
var storeRec = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'HealOmni.model.device_model',
    data: [{
        device_id: 1,
        device_name: 'device one with id'
    }, {
        device_id: 2,
        device_name: 'device two with id'
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    valueField: 'device_id',
    displayField: 'device_name_and_id',
    store: storeRec
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I've made a small fiddle for you. Compare this to your code, i hope it helps:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1m9e

Comment: comma missing in your model new field